# Why am I able to delete a file on my local machine, but failing to pass JetBrain's Academy internal tests?

Tags: java, server, client, file-handling, delete-file

**Project Description**
I'm currently working a project via JetBrains Academy's website called File Server.
In a quick summary, have a server which can either:

1. Get the contents of a files
2. Create a file
3. Delete a file

Both the server should always be running until it receives the command "exit" in the form of a string.
However, the client will only run once, and when it's completed its actions (i.e. get, create, or delete), it will terminate.

**Problem**
The problem I have is when it comes to the delete function. In the test results from JetBrains, it is saying that the file is not found (entire output below).

```
Wrong answer in test #1

You should delete a file from /server/data folder if the user requests it!

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

Server started!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > exit
The request was sent.

Server started!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 2
Enter filename: > test_purpose_N6O0XTLO.txt
Enter file content: > IDIDW22
The request was sent.
The response says that the file was created!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 2
Enter filename: > test_purpose_N6O0XTLO.txt
Enter file content: > IDIDW22
The request was sent.
The response says that creating the file was forbidden!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 1
Enter filename: > test_purpose_N6O0XTLO.txt
The request was sent.
The content of the file is: IDIDW22 

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 1
Enter filename: > test_purpose_2JK4NCL.txt
The request was sent.
The response says that the file was not found!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 3
Enter filename: > test_purpose_RB3JXD.txt
The request was sent.
The response says that the file was not found!

Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): > 3
Enter filename: > test_purpose_N6O0XTLO.txt
The request was sent.
The response says that the file was not found!
```

I've literally recreated the scenario as shown above, and everything works perfectly on my local machine.

Below is the output that I get from my IDE when I run the delete function, which is what I expect from JetBrains testing.

```
Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): 3
Enter filename: test_purpose_N6O0XTLO.txt
The request was sent.
The response says that the file was successfully deleted!
```

It's frustrating me because I do not see what the issue might be. I thought it might be because of permission issues, so I tried it on my laptop instead of my work laptop, but still get the same issues. However, I realized though I have no issues creating a file so that shouldn't be a problem.

Part of me thinks it might be something with JetBrains testing procedure.

Below is the code for the Server, and Client. There were also enums but I've left it out to avoid clutter.

```
// Server
public class Main {
    static final String path = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\Repositories\\Hyperskill\\File Server\\File Server\\task\\src\\server\\data\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        createDirectory(path);

        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 23456;

        boolean endServer = false;

        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port, 50, InetAddress.getByName(address))) {
            System.out.println("\nServer started!");

            do {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                String message = input.readUTF();

                if (message.equals("exit")) {
                    endServer = true;
                } else {
                    String[] words = message.split(" ", 3);
                    boolean isSuccessfulAction = false;
                    HTTP_COMMANDS c = HTTP_COMMANDS.valueOf(words[0]);
                    switch (c) {
                        case PUT:
                            isSuccessfulAction = createFile(path, words[1], words[2]);
                            break;
                        case GET:
                            isSuccessfulAction = getFile(path, words[1]);
                            break;
                        case DELETE:
                            isSuccessfulAction = deleteFile(path, words[1]);
                    }
                    output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(returnHTTPCode(HTTP_COMMANDS.valueOf(words[0]), isSuccessfulAction)));
                }
            } while (!endServer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not start sever!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteFile(String path, String fileName) {
        File file = new File(path + fileName);
        return file.delete();
    }

    public static boolean getFile(String path, String fileName) {
        File file = new File(path + fileName);
        return file.exists();
    }

    public static boolean createFile(String path, String fileName, String fileContent) {
        try {
            if (new File(path, fileName).exists()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                File newFile = new File(path + fileName);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile);
                writer.write(fileContent);
                writer.close();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int returnHTTPCode(HTTP_COMMANDS request, boolean actionSuccessful) {
        if (actionSuccessful) {
            return HTTP_CODES.SUCCESS.getCode();
        } else if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.PUT)) {
            return HTTP_CODES.FAIL_PUT.getCode();
        } else if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.GET)) {
            return HTTP_CODES.FAIL_GET.getCode();
        } else {
            return HTTP_CODES.FAIL_DELETE.getCode();
        }
    }

    public static void createDirectory(String path) {
        File fileDirectory = new File(path);
        if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
            fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Client
public class Client {
    static final String path = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\Repositories\\Hyperskill\\File Server\\File Server\\task\\src\\server\\data\\";
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Sleep used because it seems JetBrains is executing the client main first instead of the server main.
        // Delayed startup to ensure that server will be running first instead of the client
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 23456;

        String command;
        String fileName;

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(address), port)) {
            //boolean endServer = false;
            //do {
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.print("\nEnter action (1 - get a file, 2 - create a file, 3 - delete a file): ");
            command = scanner.nextLine();

            if (HTTP_COMMANDS.forString(command).equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.EXIT)) {
                System.out.println("The request was sent.");
                output.writeUTF(command);
                //endServer = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
                fileName = scanner.nextLine();

                switch (HTTP_COMMANDS.forString(command)) {
                    case GET:
                        output.writeUTF(get(fileName));
                        break;
                    case PUT:
                        String message = add(fileName);
                        output.writeUTF(message);
                        break;
                    case DELETE:
                        output.writeUTF(delete(fileName));
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("The request was sent.");
                String code = input.readUTF();
                printMessage(HTTP_COMMANDS.forString(command), code, fileName);
                input.close();
                output.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            //} while (!endServer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to server!");
        }

    }

    public static void printMessage(HTTP_COMMANDS request, String code, String fileName) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(code);
        if (number == HTTP_CODES.SUCCESS.getCode()) {
            if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.PUT)) {
                System.out.print("The response says that the file was created!");
            } else if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.GET)) {
                System.out.print("The content of the file is: ");
                printFromFile(fileName);
            } else if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.DELETE)) {
                System.out.print("The response says that the file was successfully deleted!");
            }
        } else {
            if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.PUT)) {
                System.out.print("The response says that creating the file was forbidden!");
            } else if (request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.DELETE) || request.equals(HTTP_COMMANDS.GET) ) {
                System.out.print("The response says that the file was not found!");
            }
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }

    public static void printFromFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path + fileName);
            Scanner scannerGet = new Scanner(file);
            while (scannerGet.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.print(scannerGet.nextLine() + " ");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(fileName + " not found!");
        }
    }

    public static String add(String fileName) {
        System.out.print("Enter file content: ");
        String fileContent = scanner.nextLine();
        return HTTP_COMMANDS.PUT + " " + fileName + " " + fileContent;
    }

    public static String get(String fileName) {
        return HTTP_COMMANDS.GET + " " + fileName;
    }

    public static String delete(String fileName) {
        return HTTP_COMMANDS.DELETE + " " + fileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't show any information on what your server did do for each request. Use a debugger to step through your server or adding a simple print statement should tell you what the server actually did for the each request which you can match up to the test harness responses: `System.out.println("action="+words[0]+" isSuccessfulAction="+isSuccessfulAction);` . Don't use string concatenation for path names, use `new File(path,fileName)`

Comment: In the server's main loop, why do you have `output.writeUTF(...)` in both the `PUT` case AND after the `switch`?

Comment: @DuncG No, I didn't add any info on what the server did mainly because the project description didn't require any. If I included information they didn't specify, it would also cause the test to fail. However I'll give it a go to see I can locate if there is a problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison Good spotting! That was a mistake from my side. I've updated the post to reflect this.